I've made a C++ header that check the printf() arguments in constexpr time. It works perfectly in gcc, but fails in clang. Any idea about the reason?
I've created a C++ header file that check in constexpr time the arguments and the format of printf() and traces with that format. Project here: https://github.com/aitorhub/printfCheck
The code can be tested online: https://godbolt.org/z/WKzbT1YEM
It works smoothly in gcc (version 8 and higher), but sadly it fails in clang, even with the newest version. Any idea why?
With Compiler: "x86-64 gcc 9.4" Options: "-std=c++17" works perfectly. But when I change the compiler to "x86-64 clang 19.1.0" it gives me compiler errors.
Any idea on how to fix it?
EDIT:
I've uploaded a simplified version of the test:
https://godbolt.org/z/eox799oWx
Same as before, With Compiler: "x86-64 gcc 9.4" "-std=c++17" works, with "x86-64 clang 19.1.0" not
template<uint32_t Start, uint32_t End, class F>
constexpr uint32_t 
constexpr_for_arg_counter (F func)
{
    uint32_t Counter = 0;
    if constexpr (Start < End)
    {
        constexpr bool atEnd = func (Start);
        
        if (atEnd == true) {
            return 0;
        }

        Counter += constexpr_for_arg_counter<Start + 1, End>( func );
    }

    return Counter;
}

constexpr bool getFieldIndices(std::string_view fmtSv, uint32_t StartIndex)
{
    return true;
}

#define  PRINTF_CHECK(fmt_literal, ...)                do{                          \
            constexpr std::string_view fmt = fmt_literal;                           \
                                                                                    \
            constexpr                                                               \
            int FmtFieldCounter =                                                   \
                constexpr_for_arg_counter<0, fmt.size()>(                           \
                        [&fmt](uint32_t Index)                                      \
                        {                                                           \
                            return getFieldIndices(fmt, Index);                     \
                        }                                                           \
                    );                                                              \
                                                                                    \
            }while(0)

int main()
{
    PRINTF_CHECK("main starts\n");

    return 0;
}

Error output:
error: constexpr variable 'atEnd' must be initialized by a constant expression
   16 |         constexpr bool atEnd = func (Start);
``


A question here should be self contained (and not rely on external links), with a [mre] copy-pasted as text.

A side note: why would you need to use the legacy printf at all in C++, where we have iostreams (in C++23 we also have std::print which is even better) ?

First, thanks for the answer. iostream doesn't support internationalization, and the majority of the C++ software projects are using C++11 or C++17. The adoption of C++23 will need more years. Aside, my C++ header works with any trace function using printf() format (%d, %s, ...)

you have to show the header. The error is not from code you included in the question. Its unclear what you expect others to do with that code

a [mcve] should be in the question

Sorry, I've edited the question and added the minimal reproducible example: https://godbolt.org/z/oW7raqz3e

its in the quesiton now, but I am still confused. There are 3 different codes that you present. One produces a compiler error from not shown  code, whats wrong with the others? Please focus the quesiton on one [mcve] with one error / output and one question

btw you do not need to add "EDIT" or similar to the question. Dont require the reader to be aware of all the edit history when reading the question. If they want to see it is already available https://stackoverflow.com/posts/79250956/revisions

you say it works with gcc but fails with clang. Then why use a godbolt link to gcc. Is there something wrong with the output from gcc?

With the godbolt example I just wanted to show that it works with gcc. Then, changing it to clang it stop working.

Why doing this this way? Just change compiler settings and it will be done automatically without changing any part of code. Also there is a great library fmt which should be preferred solution (it is also able to pretend printf behavior).

Ok, changed. The simplified version now links to the clang newest version, where the compiler error occurs. The fmt library is great, but it needs the C++20 or higher, and the industry hasn't adopted yet the newest C++ version

"The fmt library is great, but it needs the C++20 or higher" That's not true. I use fmt in C++11 projects since 2018. It should also work with even older standards. fmt started as a third-party library before it was added to the C++ standard.

Get rid of capture fixes it Demo. Not sure why it was problematic for clang.

If you stay with formats and types of original printf,  why are you not simply relying on __attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, fmtarg, firstvararg))), supported by Clang and GCC, to make the check for you?

@Aitorhub I think you have confused std::format with fmt::format and other fmt-library features. fmt-libray is third party library which is not part of C++ standard. It is so great, that standard comity decided to port parts of this library into C++ standard library - and only this has C++20 requirements. fmt-library has C++11 support and quite old compiler support:  GCC 4.9, Clang 3.4, MSVC 19.10.

Thanks @Jarod42, it looks like that fixed the problem. Im going to try it with the full versiom.

@MarekR This is a very simple example of fmt where there is a segmentation fault, a runtime error not catch at compile-time. https://godbolt.org/z/jxW6W5bfc  This simple line makes the code breaks     std::string str = "123";
fmt::print("Hello, world {0} other var: {1} \n", str);

@Aitorhub Here is compile time check in C++17 https://godbolt.org/z/hWE9jeder (in C++20 your code is checked too). This behavior is documented. Also exception thrown at runtime is much better then just undefined behavior.

But all the legacy code is still using printf(), amd that isnt going to change in the next years. On the other hand in hour example you have to put that FMT_STRING around, it isnt automatical. My C++ printf() checker could detect those errors. Where can I post my code for the other developers who want to try it?
